# Ruby Assignment Syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, language-design

A silly, syntactical question:

If the assignment operator is really a function, like

```
def value=(x)
  @value = x
end
```

without a space between the left-hand operand and the "=", then why can the assignment be made as test.value = x (with a space), but the method definition cannot be written as:

```
def value = (x)
  @value = x
end
```

with the space.  Is this simply syntax dictated by the parser?

Comment: You might ask as well, "If the milk is white, why the sky isn't?.."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`def` needs to be followed by a token for the function name, optionally followed by an argument list.  The parenthesis on the argument list is optional (e.g., `def value= x` is an appropriate definition).  `def value = (x)` looks like `def` followed by two tokens and then an argument list, which does not parse.

Comment: The parser is smart enough to know that the statement test.value = x is not a token followed by two passed parameters.  Why doesn't it parse the method definition similarly?

Comment: @inyourcorner but you aren't relying on the `def` keyword in your example

Comment: @inyourcorner:  That is entirely different from function definition.  The handler for assignment knows to check for value= methods in the receiving object (parsing is not involved).

Comment: @cam: Can you pass an operator as a parameter then?  My point being, why wouldn't the parser recognize the first operator being the operator operating on the operand?

Comment: @inyourcorner:  I'm not sure what you mean.  Operators are not objects so it doesn't make sense to "pass" them.

Comment: @cam: Sorry for the ambiguity; I tried to clarify above.  Thanks for answering and discussion; upvoted and checked.  Is my question still unclear?

Comment: @inyourcorner: I think you could make a special case in the parser for what you are asking for, but currently no special cases for assignment are necessary.  The ruby grammar is fairly complex, so special cases are probably best avoided (look at `parse.y` sometime).  That said, they did add the new { foo: "bar" } syntax for hashes so maybe you can talk matz into adding your new assignment definition syntax as well :)

Comment: @cam: Hahahaha! Thanks for the suggestion! However, I know I am not smart or conceited enough to assume I know better.  Was just making sure I wasn't missing some nuance in the language, which is complex as you've pointed out.  You've answered my question in spades: part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

That's parser/interpreter magic.

When the interpreter sees the assignment looks for a matching method.

I agree with you in this regard ( almost ), I think the assignment should be `some.value= x` ( without space between 'value' and '=' ) always.

Scala does something similar but uses an underscore `def value_= ( x: X )`