# Ruby assignment methods

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby Assignment Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963427/ruby-assignment-syntax)

I don't get the concept of an assignment method in Ruby:

```
def current_user=(user)
  @user = user
end
```

If the method is declared like that, then how can you put a space before the equals sign?

```
def some_method(user)
  self.current_user = user
end
```

Comment: it's definitely a duplicate. Sorry, I didn't see that when I searched.

Comment: No worries, it was low down in the sidebar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assignment methods are a special case of the ruby parser.  There are others like `[](..)` and `[]=(..)`.

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing magical about it, it's just a feature of the ruby parser.